# NSMigrationManager Unable to Append one Store to Another

Tags: swift, core-data, ios9, database-migration

I'm trying to merge two Core Data sql stores together (iOS 9.3), without having to read and make copies of every object in the source store (there are many complicated relationships involved). I should be able to do this with a NSMigrationManager as follows:

```
try migrationManager.migrateStoreFromURL(sourceURL, type: NSSQLiteStoreType, options: nil, withMappingModel: map, toDestinationURL: destinationURL, destinationType: NSSQLiteStoreType, destinationOptions: nil)
```

However, this gives me an error

> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134110 "An error occurred during persistent store migration." reason=Can't copy source store to destination store path {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "The file “Sample.sqlite” couldn’t be saved in the folder “Documents” because a file with the same name already exists."}

This ought not to occur. From the documentation for NSMigrationManager

> If a store does not exist at the destination URL, one is created; otherwise, the migration appends to the existing store.

However, it does not seem to want to append. Instead, it wants to overwrite and fails. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Do these two store files use the same data model?

Comment: Absolutely. I have never changed the model.

Comment: Found solution?

Comment: Sadly no. I had to bite the bullet and do it the long way- e.g. adding the source store and manually copying every attribute of every entity from the source to the destination followed by recreating all the relationships. It sucked but it works.